# Button Group Validation and Disabling Button Groups after clicking once using HTML, CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Requirements:

1. If a button is button is clicked from the following four buttons then all the buttons should be disable except for the **Next** button.
2. Alert Window should display a message when the **Next** button is clicked without clicking any other buttons and it shouldn't proceed to the next page. It should remain on the first page only.
3. It should proceed to the next page only if a button is clicked among the four buttons and then after clicking on **Next** button.

Issues faced with the following codes:

1. I am not being able to align the **Next** button towards the right-corner side of the container box.
2. Alert window is displaying the message for both the cases (even if I am selecting a button and clicking on **Next** button or even if I am clicking on **Next** button without selecting any buttons.)
3. It is proceeding to the next page after I am clicking on the  **OK** button of the alert window.

style.css

```
 h1
    {
        margin-top: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .container {
        margin: 50px;
      height: 200px;
      position: relative
    }
    .center {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 300px;
      border: 3px solid green; 
    }
```

validation.js

```
function enable_disable()
{
    $("#formDisable :input").prop("disabled", true);
}
function optionValidation (element)
{
    if ((element.id != "optionA") && (element.id != "optionB") && (element.id != "optionC") && (element.id != "optionD"))
    {
        alert ("Please choose an option.");
    }
}
```

first_page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>First</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="center">
            <form id="formDisable">
                <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                    <button onclick="enable_disable()" type="button"
                        class="btn btn-primary" id="optionA">A</button>
                    <button onclick="enable_disable()" type="button"
                        class="btn btn-primary" id="optionB">B</button>
                    <button onclick="enable_disable()" type="button"
                        class="btn btn-primary" id="optionC">C</button>
                    <button onclick="enable_disable()" type="button"
                        class="btn btn-primary" id="optionD">D.</button>
                </div>
            </form> 
            <form action="second_page.html" method="post" onsubmit="optionValidation(this)">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Next</button>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

second_page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Second</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome To Second Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please help me with these problems?

Answer (score 0):

**Let me go step by step to resolve most of your Issues:**

1. For Alignment issue of `next button` use the following CSS. I have used CSS-grid, instead of flex.

   ```
   h1 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
   }
   .container {
    margin: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
   }
   /*--- Code updated from Here Onwards ---*/
   .center {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    height: 300px;
    border: 3px solid green;
    }

   form {
     align-self: center;
     justify-self: end;
   }
   ```

2. To Disable 4 buttons even if one is clicked.And for the functionality you have want. Play the following code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // Functionality 1
  let allBtnsDisabled = false;
  const btnGroup = document.querySelectorAll(".enable-disable");

  btnGroup.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("Clicked Once");
      allBtnsDisabled = true;
      btnGroup.forEach((btnChild) => {
        btnChild.disabled = true;
      });
    });
  });

  // Functionality 2 and 3
  const formNext = document.querySelector(".form-next");
  formNext.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (allBtnsDisabled) {
      formNext.submit();
    }
    return;
  });

});
```

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.center {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

form {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="center forms-wrapper">
        <form id="formDisable">
          <div class="btn-group-vertical">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary enable-disable"
              id="optionA"
            >
              A
            </button>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary enable-disable"
              id="optionB"
            >
              B
            </button>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary enable-disable"
              id="optionC"
            >
              C
            </button>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary enable-disable"
              id="optionD"
            >
              D.
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <form action="second_page.html" method="get" class="form-next">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Next</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</html>
```

You can proceed with any other functionality from here onwards yourself.